# Make inline uploader (plupload) on options page upload to a specific folder

Tags: uploads, media, media-library, plugin-options, plupload

I’ve set up an options page for my CPT that contains the drag'n'drop upload area (just like Media → Add New). Basicly, I’ve copied all the relevant stuff from wp-admin/media-new.php and it works like charming.

[image: This is what my options page looks like]

This is the code of my options page:

```php
/**
* Callback for the submenu page
*/
function syk_bulk_import_callback() {
    
    // Taken from media-new.php
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'upload_files' ) ) {
        wp_die( __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to upload files.' ) );
    }
    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'plupload-handlers' );
    
    $post_id = 0;
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) ) {
        $post_id = absint( $_REQUEST['post_id'] );
        if ( ! get_post( $post_id ) || ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            $post_id = 0;
        }
    }
    
    if ( $_POST ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['html-upload'] ) && ! empty( $_FILES ) ) {
            check_admin_referer( 'media-form' );
            // Upload File button was clicked.
            $upload_id = media_handle_upload( 'async-upload', $post_id );
            if ( is_wp_error( $upload_id ) ) {
                wp_die( $upload_id );
            }
        }
        wp_redirect( admin_url( 'edit.php?post_type=symbol&page=syk-bulk-import' ) );
        exit;
    }
    
    $form_class = 'media-upload-form type-form validate';
    
    if ( get_user_setting( 'uploader' ) || isset( $_GET['browser-uploader'] ) ) {
        $form_class .= ' html-uploader';
    }
    
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>Massenimport</h1>
        <div id="poststuff">
            <div id="post-body" class="metabox-holder columns-1">
                <div class="postbox-container">
                    <div class="postbox">
                        <div class="postbox-header">
                            <h2>Upload files</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inside">
                            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $form_class ); ?>" id="file-form">
                                
                                <?php media_upload_form(); ?>
                                
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                var post_id = <?php echo absint( $post_id ); ?>, shortform = 3;
                                </script>
                                <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php echo absint( $post_id ); ?>" />
                                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'media-form' ); ?>
                                <div id="media-items" class="hide-if-no-js"></div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

But I need these files to **go to a custom folder within wp-content/uploads.** For images uploaded through a single cusom post’s edit screen I switch the upload dir using the `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` hook:

```php
// Upload directory switch for Symbole
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'syk_uldir_switch_pre' );
function syk_uldir_switch_pre( $file ) {
    add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'syk_uldir_switch' );
    return $file;
}

add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload', 'syk_uldir_switch_post' );
function syk_uldir_switch_post( $file ) {
    remove_filter( 'upload_dir', 'syk_uldir_switch' );
    return $file;
}

function syk_uldir_switch( $upload_dir ) {
    $is_symbol = false;
    
    // Check if upload is from custom post type edit screen
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) ) {
        $post_id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
        
        if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'symbol' )
        $is_symbol = true;
        
        if ( is_object( get_post( $post_id ) ) && get_post_type( get_post( $post_id )->post_parent ) == 'symbol' )
        $is_symbol = true;
    }
    
    // Change upload dir for post type 'symbol'
    if ( $is_symbol ) {
        $upload_dir['subdir'] = '/symbole';
        $upload_dir['path'] = $upload_dir['basedir'].$upload_dir['subdir'];
        $upload_dir['url']  = $upload_dir['baseurl'].$upload_dir['subdir'];
    }
    
    return $upload_dir;
}
```

But this won’t work for uploads coming from my CPT options screen. Can I somehow ‘detect’ where the upload comes from in my hook callback? Or can I add something in the options page telling WordPress where to upload those files?

Right now I’m not quite sure which is the right place to achieve this. Any ideas?

Comment: _Why are you putting files in a specific folder?_ What's the context behind it? Adding context/explanation for why you want this helps people understand your question better and write better answers. The answer you linked to works because the attachment posts created have a parent post of that type, but here there is no parent post. I'd also advise against copy pasting large chunks of WP core files, you're likely to face issues in the future with CSS changing, as well as security issues that get fixed in core requiring you to update your code. I also notice there is no code in your question

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your reply! Sorry, I skipped this part as I thought this would unnecessarily blow up my question. The reason is that those files should be accessible for logged-in users only. To achieve this I use a method described here: https://gist.github.com/hakre/1552239 – requests to that folder get redirected and handeled by a php file.

Comment: Also, I couldn’t find a more sophisticated way to add the uploader to my options page, so I did it according to this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/317745/181795

That’s also the reason why I didn’t enclose any code as I actually didn’t change much from the sources.

Comment: hmm that `dl-file.php` isn't too different in concept from the `ms-file.php` system WordPress has. If you used that system then the folder the files are in would be irrelevant and you could use a post meta flag to control which files require a login or not. There are other methods too, but it's important that your question is self contained.  Even if you didn't change the code you need to mention it so people can reproduce

Comment: Thanks again, Tom! I see that my original question wasn’t written like it should, sorry about that. I tried to improve it and to better secify my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution that works for me which I want to share with you. It’s more or less what EHerman posted [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/193102/181795), I just made some little changes to adapt the code to my case. Basicly the idea is to find out that the upload comes from my admin page. This is done by checking the referrer for my admin page’s name `if ( strpos( $referrer, 'page=syk-bulk-import' ) !== false ...`:

```php
add_filter( 'admin_init', 'syk_bulk_import_admin', 999 );
function syk_bulk_import_admin() {
  global $pagenow;
  $referrer = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
  if ( strpos( $referrer, 'page=syk-bulk-import' ) !== false && ( 'async-upload.php' == $pagenow || 'media-upload.php' == $pagenow ) ) {
    add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'syk_admin_uldir_switch' );
  }
}

function syk_admin_uldir_switch( $upload_dir ) {
  $upload_dir['subdir'] = '/symbole';
  $upload_dir['path'] = $upload_dir['basedir'].$upload_dir['subdir'];
  $upload_dir['url']  = $upload_dir['baseurl'].$upload_dir['subdir'];
  return $upload_dir;
}
```

PHP 8 introduced `str_contains()` which would probably be more accurate instead of the `strpos()` statement.